# sudo apt-get install gazebo > gazebo : Depends: ... but it is not installable

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, How can i fix this problem? tnx

mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~$ **sudo apt-get install gazebo**

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have

requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable

distribution that some required packages have not yet been created

or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gazebo : Depends: libboost-thread1.49.0 but it is not installable

```
      Depends: libboost-signals1.49.0 but it is not installable

      Depends: libboost-system1.49.0 but it is not installable

      Depends: libboost-filesystem1.49.0 but it is not installable

      Depends: libboost-program-options1.49.0 but it is not installable

      Depends: libboost-regex1.49.0 but it is not installable

      Depends: libboost-iostreams1.49.0 but it is not installable

      Depends: libcegui-mk2-0.7.6 but it is not installable
```

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~$

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1837/sudo-apt-get-install-gazebo-%3E-gazebo-:-depends:-...-but-it-is-not-installable/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/242/mohsen-hk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Boost1.49.0 is listed as a dependency for gazebo in the quantal version. Be sure you are not running a precise distribution using a quantal sources.list in */etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.

If that is not the reason, some extra information is would be good:

1. Ubuntu distribution being used and architecture (32/64bits)
2. Clean installation or upgrading?
3. Output from

> grep osrfoundation
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/242/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-03-18**:
tnx! (in gazebo-latest.list >> deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu quantal main) (in ros-latest.list >>deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main) i change it to0 "precise" and trying to re install with synaptic. it's work